# UWP Layout Cycle inside StackPanel when resizing children

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a `StackPanel` with 2 children that I need to resize based on the `StackPanel`s size. I attached an event handler to `SizeChanged` of the `StackPanel` and resize the element there. The problem is the event handler is fired again and again until the app crashes. What's the deal?

```
class BasicStatusTile : StackPanel {

        private TextBlock TopText { get; set; }
        private TextBlock BottomText { get; set; }

        public BasicStatusTile() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void InitializeComponent() {

            TopText = new TextBlock() {
                Text = "0",
                HorizontalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
                TextAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.TextAlignment.Center,
                FontSize = 48
            };

            BottomText = new TextBlock() {
                Text = "Speed (km/h)",
                HorizontalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
                VerticalAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.VerticalAlignment.Bottom,
                TextAlignment = Windows.UI.Xaml.TextAlignment.Center
            };

            base.Children.Insert(0, TopText);
            base.Children.Insert(1, BottomText);
            base.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

            base.SizeChanged += BasicStatusTile_SizeChanged;

        }

        private void BasicStatusTile_SizeChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.SizeChangedEventArgs e) {

            double third = base.ActualHeight / 6;

            TopText.FontSize = third * 4;
            BottomText.FontSize = third;

        }

    }
```

Comment: `StackPanel` should be a host where you put any UI elements. You shouldn't be extending it like that. A `UserControl` should be used here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened because you change FontSize of TextBlock. It fires the sizechanged event of your custom StackPanel.
You should consider what kind of control you need.
What is your purpose of using custom stackpanel with sizechanged event?

Also, FontSize is not the same as a Height of TextBlock

Comment: I ended up doing what @Justin XL suggested, subclassing `UserControl`.